# Eclipse strange error at startup

Tags: java, eclipse

So i try to start **my fresh installed eclipse** when suddenly:

[image]

I would like to use for my c++ study and **i downloaded from** [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/c.php)

**Plus interesting fact:** I have an **other Eclipse installed** which is an Android Developer Tools Bundle from Google's Android site, **and that is working perfectly, i do got java installed.**

**E D I T:**
Hah, downloaded Eclipse from other link solved my problem. Maybe it was 32 bit and my os is 64. And if not that I must say there are few things with Eclipse thats just really random.

Comment: edit your eclipse.ini with installd version of java

Comment: What is your "JAVA_HOME" set to, and what is the result of `java -version`?

Comment: In eclipse.ini change line `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5` to  `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6.0_37` i.e your installed Java version

Comment: This will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861380/jvm-terminated-exit-code-1

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I dont know what is "JAVA_HOME", btw java -version in console works with result: "java version 1.7.0_45"

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi Any chance you can move the error message to text instead of image and post an answer summarizing what you did to fix it? This sounds like something that could be useful to someone else later.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you try to run a 
64 bit eclipse distribution with a 32 bit jvm. 
The jvm distribution depends on the OS
and eclipse on the jvm.

Running a 32 bit eclipse dist with 64 bit jvm is possible.