# Eclipse(32-bit) not working after re installing accidentally deleted 32 bit java on 64 bit machine

Tags: android, eclipse

I have 32 bit eclipse luna and 32 bit java on 64 bit windows 8.1. After accidentally removing 32 bit java my eclipse throws me error of java started but returned exit code -1 i have re installed that removed 32 bit java but still it showing me error.

here is eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: ... why don't you use **64 bit** software, on a **64 bit** machine?!

Comment: From starting i'm using the 32 bit version but this morning i accidentally uninstall it . Till the date eclipse was working fine

Comment: It's `not a sane thing` to run 32 bit apps on a 64 bit machine, unless you are forced to (only because the app doesn't exist in 64 bit).

Comment: I tried all the available solution but doesn't help me. My problem solved using trio of 64 bit eclipse java and OS

Comment: Which is exactly what I was talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question is already answered here: [JVM terminated. Exit code = -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861380/jvm-terminated-exit-code-1)

Also see this: http://markonphp.com/solve-error-java-started-returned-exit-code-eclipse/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Have you checked the solution at both of the links?

Comment: yes i've already tried that solution the last remain thing is to download new  64 bit eclipse

Comment: Also try and uninstall both JDK and Eclipse once. And if you have a 64 bit system then install the 64-bit versions of JDK and Eclipse. And don't forget to set JAVA_HOME in environment variables in advance system settings.

Answer (score 0):

The -vm option should point to the bin folder, not the executable file.  (At least on my install).

Try changing it to:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin
```

I don't know if order of parameters matters, your eclipse.ini looks similar to mine but in a different order.  If you want to try changing it, this is my eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-vm
D:/Development/java/32-bit/jdk1.8.0_05/bin
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

You'd want to use your -vm path instead of what I have but otherwise should be identical.

Comment: Not working Just appear eclipse splash screen for a while and gone

Comment: I'm running Luna 32 bit on windows 7 64 bit, with a 32 bit JDK 1.8.0_05 and also 1.7.0_55 and it's working with both.  You might try copying your Java folder into the eclipse folder, and name it "jre".  Eclipse should pick up and use that one automatically.  So if your eclipse was installed to D:\eclipse, put a copy of your java_1.8 install under D:\eclipse\jre\

Comment: Added my eclipse.ini if you want to try to replace yours and see if order of parameters makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

i'm afraid this is a "KNOWN BUG "

Oracle does not provide public updates for Java 6 SE since Feb 2013 [1].

In a recent discussion on epp-dev [2] there was a lot of agreement that we should move forward. With this request I propose to increment this setting again for all packages to Java 7 for the Luna release.

please try this solution :

Change the entry in the eclipse.ini of any package to -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7 and start it with a JRE 1.7. Then you'll get an error dialog "Incompatible JVM" and a message such as "Version 1.7.x of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 1.8 or greater is required."